# SQL Server 2012 Express Report Services report builder button not visible

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssrs

I am trying to run SQL Server 2012 Express Report Services on Windows 7. I finally have it configured, but I'm not sure the missing steps that is preventing the **Report Builder** button from being visible. My desktop only has one account (administrator) and does not require any password when booting up, so I'd presume that when I launched the Report Services through an IE browser via, localhost/Reports, that I'm logged in as an administrator. Is the button not showing up because of some role is not defined and not tied to my desktop admin account?  Below is the display of the Report Services without the Report Builder button.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can still install through ClickOnce deployment via (assuming you have configured SSRS with ReportServer as the installation path):

```
http://<servername>/reportserver/reportbuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application
```

It's still functional, but it's not full-featured.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337424.aspx)

For example, [Report Models](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159752%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) are not supported and neither are ad-hoc queries through Report Models. This is an SSRS Express limitation which will manifest in Report Builder. Additionally, the language of the [Supported Features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) of SSRS Express are somewhat ambiguous (nature of the English language) especially with regards to this line:

> Ad hoc reporting through semantic models and Report Builder is not supported.

What does the "and" connect and how does it connect them? Is it the clause "semantic models and Report Builder" or is Ad hoc reporting not supported through both semantic models and Report Builder. Unfortunately, the answer to this question could be more readily parsed at [Linguistics.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com). But I digress. Suffice it to say, Report Builder *is* available to you in SSRS Express.